# java convert UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to Array

Tags: java, java-8

I have `ArrayList` `collection` with an elements - `[10, 20, 30]`

when I use

```
(collection).toArray(new Integer[0])
```

everything works fine.

But sometimes I have to convert `UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` `collection` to array.

[image]

So when I use the same code:

```
(collection).toArray(new Integer[0])
```

I receive an exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:407)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.toArray(Collections.java:1034)
```

How to properly convert collection in this case ? Is there any collection type agnostic `toArray()` method implementation (for example at Apache commons) ?

Comment: How are these collections declared?

Comment: `Collection.toArray()` throws `ArrayStoreException` - if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following code generates an ArrayStoreException:

```
     Object x[] = new String[3];
     x[0] = new Integer(0);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html

Comment: Thanks. After debug I have found an issue. Collection sometimes contains Long values instead of Integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can always convert any type of collection to an array via the `Stream`.

```
Integer[] intArray = collection.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```